# Dynamic document loading with @DocumentRererence for Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

Is there a way to stop loading the referenced document marked with **@DocumentReference** during an api call as it'd make the db calls heavy in case there are multiple referenced documents? Or is there better way to do that? I have tried **@DBRef** but that won't solve the problem as the existing database looks something like this:

```
{
"_id" : "833f7d",
"name" : "Del Rey Books",
"arconym" : "DRB",
"foundationYear" : 1977,
"books" : [
    NumberLong(300000),
    NumberLong(395652)
 ]
}
```

and @DBRef would make the db entry to look something like this if I save new data (therefore won't solve the problem) :

```
{
"_id" : "833f7d",
"name" : "Del Rey Books",
"arconym" : "DRB",
"foundationYear" : 1977,
"books" : [
    {
        "$ref" : "book",
        "$id" : 300000
    },
    {
        "$ref" : "book",
        "$id" : 395652
    }
]
}
```

The domain class looks something like this:

```
class Publisher {
 // ...
 @DocumentReference(lazy = true)
 List<Book> books;
}
```

The **GET** api request fetches the whole referenced document in response body, but along with it also adds the keys (i) target - containing the same referenced document all over again. (ii) source - containing the id of the referenced object again. Something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "833f7d",
    "name" : "Del Rey Books",
    "arconym" : "DRB",
    "foundationYear" : 1977,
    "books" : [
        {
            "id" : 300000,
            "isbn13" : "978-0345503800",
            "title" : "The Warded Man",
            "pages" : 432,
            "target": {
              id" : 300000,
              "isbn13" : "978-0345503800",
              "title" : "The Warded Man",
              "pages" : 432,
           },
           "source" : 300000

        },
        {
            "id" : 395652,
            "isbn13" : "978-0345503800",
            "title" : "The Sailor",
            "pages" : 420,
            "target": {
              id" : 395652,
              "isbn13" : "908-093830380",
              "title" : "The Sailor",
              "pages" : 420,
           },
           "source" : 395652
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the significance of **target, source** all over again in the response body?
Also is there any other way to have references but not load the references in the response body during an API call? I was expecting **(lazy = true)** would do so, but it doesn't.

Comment: This is the major reason why Document/Entity and DTOs must be two different classes. But in case you want to go ahead with the same class then along with `@DocumentReference` add `@JsonIgnore` annotation too to the reference field. This will prevent the getter call while serialisation.

Comment: @MohammedAtif, `@JsonIgnore` might help but I am ok with loading just the id field in that case. `@JsonIgnoreProperties` might come handy for the same but in most of the cases I have around 15-20 fields that I might have to ignore so it doesn't seem like an better alternative as well. How would you suggest embedding another field and not make the db call heavy at the same time? I am ok with just the id, but i don't really need the whole referenced document to load at the same time.

Comment: There are two ways to achieve this. Simplest way is to remove the DocumentReference altogether and directly store String id instead of whole object. If you need this referenced document in the code then you can fetch it using repository again.